# How do I generate the DB schema or migration files for an existing RoR model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, schema

Is there a way to generate a migration file or db schema file from an existing RoR model? I lost my original migration files and the db has been deleted and I don't want to write either by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a db/schema.rb file that is created after your migrations have been run.  If you don't have this file in your repo and you don't have a db backup then there is nothing ActiveRecord can do for you.

Comment: Thanks. Don't have that file either. But I'll stop looking for a solution now and just manually write the schema.

Comment: Yeah I have git setup I just didn't commit any of my changes recently enough for comfort.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like it would be possible to me.  An ActiveRecord model's attributes are determined by the database schema.  There is not usually any code within the model that explicitly states what the model consists of (except for associations).